# I always need to press "S" to change the block cursor to the line cursor on vs code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

[why do I always need to press "S" to change the block cursor to the line cursor on vs code?, I want to change the default cursor mode to the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5P9c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Controls the cursor style.
"editor.cursorStyle": "line",
```

from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings VSCode settings.json defaults